# What are the limits on GMSGroundOverlay?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

What are the limits on GMSGroundOverlay? This would be things like file size, resolution, etc..

I'm using Google Maps SDK 1.5. I created a ground overlay from an image that was 4836x5557 72 dpi 6.6 MB. That image did not show up. When I reduced the image to 3481x4000 72 dpi 4.5 MB, that overlay image did show up.

I did try some permutations of resolutions and file sizes but couldn't nail down the pattern. I did not see any documentation of limits in the docs nor headers.

This is important to me as we have customers who use want map overlays, and to be able to provide them up front with the constraints for the overlay graphics is useful and saves much time for all involved.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you expand on your use case? Is there a reason why you can't set up your images as a tapestry of map tiles?

Comment: It's about providing options to our customers. Their needs, the cost of our labor to produce the tiles (it's less labor intensive to make a ground overlay than tiles), etc.. Yes, tiles are generally a better option and we support tiles (both from within the app bundle, and hosted on our servers). But if we can satisfy customer need another way (that's both satisfactory and less costly), we'd like to provide that option. Each overlay approach has pros and cons, and providng our customers (and ourselves) with as much information to weigh those pros and cons is why I'm asking.

Comment: I'll ask our eng team if we can publish numbers, but the difficulties come down to managing hardware limits, particularly GL RAM, which means the limits are both Operating System revision and hardware dependent. If I were you I'd look at ways you can make providing tilesets from their large raster images...

Comment: Sure. Tiles are certainly a better way to go and we will prefer that. But again, balancing technical reality against business need. That said, even if you can't publish numbers, some manner of solid guidelines would be useful; something to help is determine what can work, will work, won't work, best practices, etc.. Anything to help give solid guidance instead of now, just stabbing in the dark. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Overlay is rendered using OpenGL as a single texture, so the limitation on its size is probably the same as limitation on OpenGL texture size.

On the latest devices maximum texture size is 4096×4096: 
https://apptyrant.com/2014/04/19/max-opengl-texture-sizes-for-various-ios-devices/

The solution is either to limit the overlay size or to use [Tiles API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/tiles).